# SAPUI5: Sort data based on combined columns

Tags: odata, sapui5

There is a possibility in OData to pass a `fnComparator` for `sap.ui.model.Sorter`.

```
new sap.ui.model.Sorter(sPath, bDescending?, vGroup?, fnComparator?)
```

Here is the [api](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Sorter.html#.defaultComparator).

My problem is that I have 2 columns in my odata. Column A have some positive and negative numbers and column B has some units.

I need to have a sorting like this:

-M < -w < -d < -h < -m < -s < 0 < s < m < h < d < w < M

Actually the minutes that are negative are less than negative seconds.

Now problem is that I can just pass the path of one columns. Is there any possibility to pass 2 paths in the time of creation of a sorter and get a value like "C1C2" which C1 comes from column C1 and C2 from the second column.

I don't have access to OData server to make a combined column in back-end.

Comment: what are you passing as "sPath"?

Comment: It is part of the syntax in API

Comment: I know, what I meant was that if you are passing something like `"myPath"`, you can replace it with an empty string `""` and you should get the entire object as a parameter of the `fnComparator`.